# How do you insulate with XPS around interior basement windows?

Tags: insulation, basement

I'm using 2" XPS to insulate my interior basement walls.
How do I work around windows?
Do I cut it flush with the concrete opening?
Do I spray expanding foam to seal the XPS against the concrete around the opening?
Should I spray expanding foam in the gap between the concrete and the window?

I'm having a hard time finding any resources for this question across the web so any advice on this issue is helpful.